# How to set the highest-valued 1 bit to 0 , prefferably in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bit

If, for example, I have the number 20:

`0001 0100`

I want to set the highest valued 1 bit, the left-most, to 0.

So

`0001 0100`

will become

`0000 0100`

I was wondering which is the most efficient way to achieve this.

Preferrably in c++.

I tried substracting from the original number the largest power of two like this,

```
unsigned long long int originalNumber;
unsigned long long int x=originalNumber;
               x--;
               x |= x >> 1;
               x |= x >> 2;
               x |= x >> 4;
               x |= x >> 8;
               x |= x >> 16;
               x++;
               x >>= 1;

            originalNumber ^= x;
```

,but i need something more efficient.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Yes, i tried subtracting from the original number the highest power of two,using bitwise to calculate the highest power.

Comment: Instead of substracting, try using XOR ?

Comment: Please don't post code or formatted text in a comment! Edit your question to include all relevant information.

Comment: Take a look at [bit fiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Comment: Shift left your value one by one with <<. Tests the highest bit with a binary and. If it's set, shift once more, to get rid of the bit, and then right shift to bring the other bits at their original place !

Comment: So, you've benchmarked it, and you need it to go faster because it doesn't fit into the time allotted. So, the first thing you must tell us is: **how much faster does it need to go**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part is finding the most significant bit, or counting the number of leading zeroes. Everything else is can be done more or less trivially with left shifting 1 (by one less), subtracting 1 followed by negation (building an inverse mask) and the `&` operator.

The well-known [bit hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) site has several implementations for the problem of finding the most significant bit, but it is also worth looking into compiler intrinsics, as all mainstream compilers have an intrinsic for this purpose, which they implement as efficiently as the target architecture will allow (I tested this a few years ago using GCC on x86, came out as single instruction). Which is fastest is impossible to tell without profiling on your target architecture (fewer lines of code, or fewer assembly instructions are not always faster!), but it is a fair assumption that compilers implement these intrinsics not much worse than you'll be able to implement them, and likely faster.
Using an intrinsic with a somewhat intellegible name may also turn out easier to comprehend than some bit hack when you look at it 5 years from now.

Unluckily, although a not entirely uncommon thing, this is not a standardized function which you'd expect to find in the C or C++ libraries, at least there is no standard function that I'm aware of.

For GCC, you're looking for `__builtin_clz`, VisualStudio calls it `_BitScanReverse`, and Intel's compiler calls it `_bit_scan_reverse`.

Alternatively to counting leading zeroes, you may look into what the same Bit Twiddling site has under "Round up to the next power of two", which you would only need to follow up with a right shift by 1, and a NAND operation. Note that the 5-step implementation given on the site is for 32-bit integers, you would have to double the number of steps for 64-bit wide values.

Comment: Surely in the last paragraph, that would only one step more for 64bit numbers?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <limits.h>

uint32_t unsetHighestBit(uint32_t val) {
    for(uint32_t i = sizeof(uint32_t) * CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(val & (1 << i)) {
            val &= ~(1 << i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

#### Explanation

Here we take the size of the type `uint32_t`, which is 4 bytes. Each byte has 8 bits, so we iterate 32 times starting with `i` having values 31 to 0.

In each iteration we shift the value 1 by `i` to the left and then bitwise-and (`&`) it with our value. If this returns a value != 0, the bit at `i` is set. Once we find a bit that is set, we bitwise-and (`&`) our initial value with the bitwise negation (`~`) of the bit that is set.

For example if we have the number 44, its binary representation would be `0010 1100`. The first set bit that we find is bit 5, resulting in the mask `0010 0000`. The bitwise negation of this mask is `1101 1111`. Now when bitwise and-ing `&` the initial value with this mask, we get the value `0000 1100`.

#### In C++ with templates

This is an example of how this can be solved in C++ using a template:

```
#include <limits>

template<typename T> T unsetHighestBit(T val) {
    for(uint32_t i = sizeof(T) * numeric_limits<char>::digits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(val & (1 << i)) {
            val &= ~(1 << i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: will you plz elaborate how it will work.

Comment: Sorry there were some errors, fixed it and added an explanation ;)

Comment: I believe that `std::numeric_limits<char>::digits` looks more verbose but better than `8`.

Comment: Yes you could do this, but you'd have to repeat the type - like this it's C compatible, too.

Comment: For compatible with `C` you can use `CHAR_BIT` from `limits.h`.

Comment: Right, added this to the answer. :)

Comment: How is this better than what the OP came up with by himself?

Comment: It's not dependent of the size of the type.

Comment: So in other words, it's not better. OP asked for faster, not for more general.

Comment: You still won't find a faster way...

Comment: Sure you will, the bitscan solution for one. Even the original solution from OPs question is a good contender, but hard to guess.

Comment: I must correct, I meant "You won't find a *much* faster way".

Answer (score 3):

If you're constrained to 8 bits (as in your example), then just precalculate all possible values in an array (byte[256]) using any algorithm, or just type it in by hand.

Then you just look up the desired value:

```
   x = lookup[originalNumber]
```

Can't be much faster than that. :-)

UPDATE: so I read the question wrong.

But if using 64 bit values, then break it apart into 8 bytes, maybe by casting it to a byte[8] or overlaying it in a union or something more clever. After that, find the first byte which are not zero and do as in my answer above with that particular byte. Not as efficient I'm afraid, but still it is at most 8 tests (and in average 4.5) + one lookup.

Of course, creating a byte[65536} lookup will double the speed.

Comment: I'm not constrained to 8 bits, I used `unsigned long long int` in my example,also. 1<<x << 2^64 -1

Comment: And once he has found the number in the array, what should he do with it?

Comment: @maxdev the value at index 00010100 would be 00000100, so that would be the result sought.

Comment: Note: for 64 bits, we can find the highest non zero byte in 3 tests (on `uint32_t`, then `uint16_t` and finally on `uint8_t`).

Comment: Interval halving. I love it. :-)

Comment: ...and if the lookup is 16-bit then we only need two tests.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will turn off the right most bit:

```
bool found = false;
int bit, bitCounter = 31;
while (!found)  {
    bit = x & (1 << bitCounter);
    if (bit != 0)   {
        x &= ~(1 << bitCounter);
        found = true;
    }
    else if (bitCounter == 0)
        found = true;
    else
        bitCounter--;
}
```

Comment: How is this better than what the OP came up with by himself?

Answer (score -1):

I know method to set more right non zero bit to 0.

```
a & (a - 1)
```

It is from Book: [Warren H.S., Jr. - Hacker's Delight.](http://www.hackersdelight.org/)

You can reverse your bits, set more right to zero and reverse back. But I do now know efficient way to invert bits in your case.